# Angular js curly brackets displayed as text

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to do a simple function in my angular js trial.

I cannot get the method call to work, it only displays it all as text. I cannot figure out what I have done wrong in such a small thing.

This is my entire code and below is a screenshot of the result.

The html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>

<body ng-app="beerApp">
<div ng-controller="contentC">
    <div>
        <ul>
            <select ng-model="currentItem" ng-options="item.name for item in items"></select>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>{{ currentItem.name }}</p>
        <p>{{ currentItem.country }}</p>
        <p>{{ average(currentItem.ratings) }}</p>
        <p ng-repeat="rating in currentItem.ratings">{{ rating.rating }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The js

```
var app = angular.module('beerApp', []);
app.controller('contentC', function($scope) {
$scope.items = [
    {name:'Rignes',country:'Norway', ratings:[
        {"rating":3}, {"rating":3}, {"rating":2}]},
    {name:'Pripps',country:'Sweden', ratings:[
        {"rating":2}, {"rating":3}, {"rating":5}]},
    {name:'Tuborg',country:'Denmark', ratings:[
        {"rating":5}, {"rating":4}, {"rating":3}]}
];
$scope.currentItem = {name:'Nothing'};
$scope.average = function (data) {
    console.log("called")
    var sum = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < data.lenght; i++){
        sum += parseInt(data[i].rating);
    }
    var avg = sum/data.lenght;
    return avg;
};
});
```

[curly brackets displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIiUR.png)

**Corrected js code**

```
$scope.average = function (data) {
        var sum = 0; 
        var ratings = 0;
        try {
            for (var d in data){
                sum += parseInt(data[d].rating);
                ratings++;
            }
        } catch (error) {
            sum = 0;
        }
        var avg = sum/ratings;
        return avg;
    };
```

Comment: Your function expects an argument (`data`) but you're not passing anything in. Also it's spelled `length` not `lenght`.

Comment: When injection services you have to do like so

('contentC', ['$scope', function($scope){...

Comment: @luk492: Angular can pick the references up automatically just fine from unminified scripts and there are tools to put in the annotations for minified scripts. Writing them out by hand is just error prone. Sometimes maybe necessary, but I say best avoided when possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `average` function is throwing an error so Angular is leaving the binding as-is because there's no sensible value to bind to it.

There are a couple of errors in your code:

- `length` is spelt incorrectly
- you're not passing the argument required for average
- I think that you need to loop through `data.ratings.length` rather than `data.length`
- your default `currentItem` does not have a ratings property.

Working demo http://codepen.io/anon/pen/reqbZG

```
var app = angular.module('beerApp', []);

app.controller('contentC', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
        {name:'Rignes',country:'Norway', ratings:[
            {"rating":3}, {"rating":3}, {"rating":2}]},
        {name:'Pripps',country:'Sweden', ratings:[
            {"rating":2}, {"rating":3}, {"rating":5}]},
        {name:'Tuborg',country:'Denmark', ratings:[
            {"rating":5}, {"rating":4}, {"rating":3}]}
    ];

    $scope.currentItem = {name:'Nothing', ratings: []};
    $scope.average = function (data) {
        var sum = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < data.ratings.length; i++){
            sum += parseInt(data.ratings[i].rating);
        }
        var avg = sum/data.ratings.length;
        return avg;
    };
});
```

And the slightly updated HTML (average method call):

```
<!-- snip -->
    <p>{{ currentItem.name }}</p>
    <p>{{ currentItem.country }}</p>
    <p>{{average(currentItem)}}</p>
    <p ng-repeat="rating in currentItem.ratings">{{ rating.rating }</p>
<!-- snip -->
```

Comment: Even with correct lenght I found out that I still had an error trying to get the length of the json array. Adding the corrected code to the question.

Comment: Your demo code got me going but due to an upcoming twist I have to avoid sending in the entire _currentItem_.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
    <p>{{average()}}</p>
```

For

```
    <p>{{average(items)}}</p>
```

Also, try checking your console (ctrl+shift+i)